Subir Proyecto Laravel a Hostin Compartido y dependencias
Tengo un proyecto en Laravel 10 funcionando en un hostin compartido.
En mi local tuve que instalar composer require maatwebsite/excel.
En local anda todo perfecto, ahora, al momento de subir las dependencias creadas y carpetas, no funciona y recibo como error: Class "Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel" not found
Ya subi composer.lock, composer.json y la carpeta maatwebsite en vendor, y me sigue diciendo Class "Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel" not found.
Que otros archivos debo subir manualmente a mi servidor para que  funcione tal cual está funcionando en mi local? GRCIAS!!!!

Probablemente te falte el archivo autoload.php

El autoload.php es identico en local como en producción. Gracias @porloscerrosΨ

Borraste a cache?

Que carpeta seria que habria que  borrar? @porloscerrosΨ

Lo que haya en /bootstrap/cache/ menos el .gitignore. No podes correr un comando via ssh?

debieras subir toda la carpeta vendor
